# How to not feel anything when people shout over me?

Tags: emotion

At work, sometimes, we get in touch with kind people. But often, we are with rude people, and here, we cannot control others, even if they shout... my question is ... how to not feel the shouting ? I tried to consider people like objects in my mind, but without any success...

Comment: I am really not sure this is possible. Think about changing your profession where you would have less contact with customers.

Comment: Felling emotions is an unconscious thing. YOU have no control over it, what you can control instead is how you response to those feelings. People who don't feel emotions are mentally ill, i.e Sociopaths, Psychopaths and Schizoid personality disorders etc... It's like asking how can i not hear sounds, well you need to be deaf to do that! right? From my own experience i struggle with this a lot since I'm an HSP (Highly Sensitive Person), "trust me, i know the feeling". My personal advice is to hang in there until you find a job that suits your preferences, Good Luck.